# Can't publish initial build of app in Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

When I try to publish a release in the Google Play Console, I constantly get this error:

`Your app cannot be published yet. Complete the steps listed on the Dashboard.`

And yes, I have indeed completed all the steps listed in the dashboard. I am using the new Play Console Beta, this is possibly related. What do I need to do before I can publish a release? Is there a hidden step?

Comment: Google annoys me. Why do I have to provide so much information for a closed alpha test? I want to show a preview of an app without all the headache of setting everything up.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

After some searching, I found the button 'Use classic Play Console'. Apparently there are some steps to be finished that are simply not visible in the Beta:

- Click on `Use classic Play Console`
- Go to `Pricing & distribution`
- Check the `Content guidelines` checkmark
- Check the `US export laws` checkmark
- Press `Save draft`

And you're good to go!

[image]

Comment: I've found multiple bugs like this in the Beta Play Console. I encourage everyone who encounters this to pass along the feedback to Google. In the top right corner, there is a feedback button. Hopefully the fix it soon! At least before they decommission the old play store 

Comment: Couldnt find Use Classic Play Console Wheres that ?

Comment: @albatross It's in the main menu, on the left, all the way at the bottom. I've edited the original answer to show a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks I ve found it 5 mins before view your response =) come here to edit for other users thanks you did it Jasper

Comment: You would think Google has tested the most basic primary function of the console.. uploading apps..

Comment: This is still present, even with the notification banner that the old console will be shut down on 2nd November. Amazing.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me. Still the issue present.

Comment: I had to switch the app to payed (and set the price) and then back to free...

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem and fix it. the problem caused by google console because they added one additional task in the app content about wither your app is consider a news app or not. so go to the inbox in your app and you will find that message from google click and you will be leaded to the content that you should fill. I hope that help any one having that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. It was regarding setting your app as free from the App Pricing section as my application was free. So after setting that, I released my app.