# Can't figure out why I cannot publish Android App From Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

## The Problem

I cannot figure out why I cannot publish ethier to Google Play or create a closed test. Whenever I try to create a release or publish I get the message your app cannot be published yet. See below.
[image]

### Additional Context

There are no steps on the dashboard for me to complete and there is no indication on what I need to do.

My problem is similar to this [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353002/cant-publish-initial-build-of-app-in-google-play-console). I am making a new post as

- There is no option to use the classic Google Play Console.
- For people having this problem in the future there should be strategy they can use to solve/troubleshoot this problem themselves.

Comment: did you figure it out?  I am in the 'App content' section and it says nothing needs attention ('all caught up').

Answer (score 0):

From `Google Play Console` go to `App content` from side menu.

You will find `To do` section, complete it then submit your app.